# ListView - No tiene memoria

Tags: javascript, android, xml, listview

Estoy empezando a hacer una app de fechas.
Pero ya empiezo con los primeros problemas. creo un listview (para añadir los cumpleaños) pero cuando cierro la APP toda la información almacenada se borra.

Mi codigo:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context ctx;
    private List<personas> listaProducto;
    private EditText edNombre, edDescripcion;
    ArrayAdapter<personas> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ctx=this;
        addView();
    }

    private void addView() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        edDescripcion =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDescripcionProducto);
        edNombre =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNombreProducto);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listaProducto.add(get(edNombre.getText().toString(), edDescripcion.getText().toString(), R.drawable.add_sinfoto));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                edNombre.getText().clear();
                edDescripcion.getText().clear();
            }
        });

        // create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        ListView listaView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ListaAdapter(MainActivity.this, getListaProductos());
        listaView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listaView.refreshDrawableState();
    }

    private List<personas> getListaProductos(){
        listaProducto= new ArrayList<personas>();
        String [] titulos;
        String [] descripciones;
        titulos=  ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos);
        descripciones= ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descripciones);

        int [] imagenes= new int[]{
        };

        for (int i=0; i<imagenes.length; i++){
            listaProducto.add(get(titulos[i],descripciones[i],imagenes[i]));
        }
        //listaProducto.get(0).setSelected(true);
        return listaProducto;
    }

    private personas get(String titulo, String descripcion, int imagen ) {
        return new personas(titulo, descripcion, imagen);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.menu_borrar:
                for (int i=listaProducto.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
                    if(listaProducto.get(i).isSelected()){
                        listaProducto.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ListaAdapter.java

```
public class ListaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<personas> {
    private final List<personas> list;
    private final Context context;

    public ListaAdapter(Context context, List<personas> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_fila, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {//Un miembro protegido es accesible dentro de su clase y por instancias de clases derivadas.
        protected ImageView imageview_alimento;
        protected TextView tvTitulo;
        protected TextView tvDescripcion;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator =LayoutInflater.from(context);// Activity.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_fila, null);// java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
            viewHolder.tvDescripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
            viewHolder.imageview_alimento = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImagView_Producto);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override                    //checkbox ,                activado:true-false
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    personas element = (personas) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.tvTitulo.setText(list.get(position).getTitulo());
        holder.tvDescripcion.setText(list.get(position).getDescripcion());
       holder.imageview_alimento.setImageResource(list.get(position).getId_imagen());

        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public personas getItem(int position) {
         return super.getItem(position);
    }
}
```

personas.java

```
public class personas {
     private String titulo;
     private String descripcion;
     private int id_imagen;
     private boolean selected;

     public personas(String titulo, String descripcion, int id_imagen) {
         this.titulo = titulo;
         this.descripcion = descripcion;
         this.id_imagen = id_imagen;
         this.selected = false;
     }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public int getId_imagen() {
        return id_imagen;
    }

    public void setId_imagen(int id_imagen) {
        this.id_imagen = id_imagen;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

content_main.xml

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/edNombreProducto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
    android:hint="Nombre" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/edDescripcionProducto"
    android:hint="Fecha" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_fila

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImagView_Producto"

            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_width="90dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nombre"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="255dp" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDescripcion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="16/09/1993"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias!

EDITO2:

MainActivity.java: @sioesi

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Context ctx;
private List<personas> listaProducto;
private EditText edNombre, edDescripcion;
ArrayAdapter<personas> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Set<Persona> set = prefs.getStringSet("personas", null);
    List<Persona> listaProductos =new ArrayList<Persona>(set);
    ctx=this;
    addView();


}



private void addView() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    edDescripcion =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDescripcionProducto);
    edNombre =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNombreProducto);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            listaProducto.add(get(edNombre.getText().toString(), edDescripcion.getText().toString(), R.drawable.add_sinfoto));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            edNombre.getText().clear();
            edDescripcion.getText().clear();



        }
    });

    // create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
    ListView listaView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new ListaAdapter(MainActivity.this, getListaProductos());
    listaView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listaView.refreshDrawableState();

}


private List<personas> getListaProductos(){
    listaProducto= new ArrayList<personas>();
    String [] titulos;
    String [] descripciones;
    titulos=  ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos);
    descripciones= ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descripciones);




    int [] imagenes= new int[]{


    };



    for (int i=0; i<imagenes.length; i++){
        listaProducto.add(get(titulos[i],descripciones[i],imagenes[i]));

    }
    //listaProducto.get(0).setSelected(true);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Editor edit=prefs.edit();

    Set<Persona> set = new HashSet<Persona>();
    set.addAll(listaProducto);
    edit.putStringSet("personas", set);
    edit.commit();
    return listaProducto;
}


private personas get(String titulo, String descripcion, int imagen ) {
    return new personas(titulo, descripcion, imagen);
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    switch (id){




        case R.id.menu_borrar:

            for (int i=listaProducto.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
                if(listaProducto.get(i).isSelected()){
                    listaProducto.remove(i);

                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




            break;
        default:
            break;

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías incluir el error que te sale al cerrar??

Comment: No me sale ningún error, simplemente no se queda guardado los cambios que realizo desde el móvil. Añado un texto en 'edNombreProducto' se crea bien, cierro la app y al abrirla no aparece, vuelve a empezar de cero @josego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo no tiene persistencia de datos, lo que agregas en el `listView` vive y muere dentro de la instancia de tu app. Hay dos maneras para esto :

Crear una base de datos en tu aplicacion e ir guardando los datos ahi. O guardar en `sharedPreferences` te dejo un ejemplo de esta ultima.

Para guardarlo

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit(); 
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = gson.toJson(listaProductos); 
editor.putString("personas", json); 
editor.commit();
```

Para leerlo

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString("personas", null);
Type type = new TypeToken < ArrayList <personas>> () {}.getType();
listaProductos = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Esto va a solucionar el problema que no puedes mantener los datos, **PERO** lo **MEJOR** es que hagas persistencia como corresponde que es con una base de datos.

Te dejo un [tutorial](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/) completo de como crear una base de datos en Android.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de añadirlo a mi código, edito el primer comentario para que veas como lo añado para ver si me puedes decir donde me equivoco. Lo añado en personas.java, si me pudieses poner un ejemplo de como añadirlo, te lo agradeceria, gracias!

Comment: No amigo, esto no va en la clase persona, si no que va donde agregas una persona a lista. En el metodo `private List<personas> getListaProductos()` luego de terminar el for que agrega las personas, debes agregar este codigo

Comment: Entonces iría en listadapter verdad? @sioesi

Comment: Tampoco, tu listaAdapter se encarga de cargar el listview con un formato custom. Edite mi respuesta. Para que veas donde van cada uno de los metodos de mi respuesta

Comment: Edito el primer comentario para que veas como lo he añadido, creo que ahora si está bien pero me da varios errores, dejo una captura en el primer mensaje de los errores, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @UserNameYo estas trabajando con android-studio, por lo tanto debes hacer los imports necesarios, creare una sala de chat y te dejare el link para que vayas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50775/discussion-between-sioesi-and-usernameyo).

Answer (score 1):

No te esta guardando permanentemente porque no estas utilizando una base de datos para almacenar tu información para volver a utlizar en caso que cierres la app. 
Al estas usando tu app, todo se guarda en memoria, pero cuando cerras y volves a abrir, se te borra todo. 
La única forma que permanezca es que lo guardes en una base de datos y luego lo recuperes.

Hace un tiempo realice un [post](http://proyectosbeta.net/2013/07/optimizar-un-listview/) donde muestra como se guarda un listview en una base de datos y como recuperarlo. Ademas que sea mas optimo y no tarde en listar. Espero que te sirva para